# parse query findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock without data match criteria then without perform closure

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have designed PFQuery to read data from Parse.com using findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock, however, parse.com without data match criteria. But I don't know why program without enter -> Void in closure

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Ordermaster")

query.whereKey("username", equalTo: currentUser!.username!)
query.addDescendingOrder("date")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    //why not execute here
    if error == nil && objects!.count > 0 {
        let object = objects![0]
        self.closeDateLabel.text = object.objectForKey("date") as? String
    } else {
        self.closeDateLabel.text = "Without data"
    }

}
```